# Change background of title and header in pivot control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Phone 7 application, I'm using a pivot control. Now I'd like to change the background of its title and header area. How can I achieve this?

Is there an overall template for the pivot control that can be customized?

I've already tried to set the background of the grid containing the pivot control to the header color and then to set the background of each pivot item to the original background color. It looks good on first sight. But when you wipe the pivot item to the left to display the second item, an area colored in the header color appears between the two pivot items. So that approach is not working.

Furthermore I've tried to customize the template of the title and the header item. But these templates only cover the area of the text itself, not the whole header and template area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the variant with changing the control's template. Change the Background="Red" to whatever brush you want.

```
<Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="controls:Pivot">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Pivot">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid Background="Red" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
          <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                Grid.Row="2" />
          <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="24,17,0,-7"/>
          <controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement"
                                                  Grid.Row="1"/>
          <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

....

<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}">

....
```

Comment: @Ostemar I realize this is an olde post but are you aware of a way to style each header item individually? For example; I would like to have a different image for each header item.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the Title and Header templates are only the actual text areas. It might be possible to override the whole template of the Pivot control, but an easier way would be to just add a colored rectangle behind it.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
  <Rectangle 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Height="150" Fill="Red" />
  <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
        <Grid/>
    </controls:PivotItem>
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
        <Grid/>
    </controls:PivotItem>
  </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I had the same idea today, and it works. However, is there any guarantee that the title and the header will always have a total height of 150 pixel (or rather 131 in my case)?

Comment: It is guaranteed as long as your page is tied to a single orientation. If not, then the width of the area will change once the user rotates the phone.

Comment: No, the 150 was just taken out of the air. But it works if you support landscape as well 'cause the pivot title+header area's height seems to be the same in both portrait and landscape.

Comment: @Dennis - the width has nothin to do with it since I use HorizontalAlignment="Stretch". The only question is the height and that stays the same in both portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the header template, which is usually a better option since you won't have to worry about custom positioning and alignment:

```
<controls:Pivot>
  <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Grid Background="White"><TextBloc>Your Header Here</TextBlock></Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

That being said, you are applying the background to an auto-resizing grid - of course, you can resize it on your own to adjust it to the right size. Same applies to each PivotItem, if that's where you want to change the title - just bind those to a similar DataTemplate.

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all. As I wrote in my question, the header template covers just the text and neither the title nor the area just around the header and title text. Furthermore, your code sample also misses a placeholder for the header text. The net result of your code is that the header is gone completely.

Comment: Edited - all you need is a TextBlock there. If you really need to you can customize the base template by going into Expression Blend and getting the original template for the control. Modify it to your needs and then simply use it in your application as a custom DataTemplate.