# Need to change foreground color of a header pivot item dynamically

Tags: c#, silverlight, foreground, pivotitem

I have this:

```
<controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding}" />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

But Foreground="{Binding}" is not working. How can I do that?
Thanks!!

Comment: Related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245046/change-background-of-title-and-header-in-pivot-control

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with code behind:

XAML:

```
<Pivot x:Uid="AppTitle" x:Name="MyPivot" Title="" Foreground="White">
    <PivotItem>
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <TextBlock x:Uid="HeaderTextFromResources" Foreground="White" Text="" />
        </PivotItem.Header>
   ...
```

C#:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PivotItem pivotItem in MyPivot.Items)
    {
        if (pivotItem == MyPivot.Items[MyPivot.SelectedIndex])
        {
            // Header of the selected item to white
            ((TextBlock)pivotItem.Header).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
        else
        {
            // Headers of other items to slightly darker
            ((TextBlock)pivotItem.Header).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 230, 230, 230));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this wont work if you are using ItemsSource={Binding ..} because pivotItem will be of any type.