# WP7 C# - How to change style of Pivot header

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

I need to change Pivot header background and padding (top menu of Pivot control where are titles of pivot items).

I try this:

```
    <controls:Pivot Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="#666666" Margin="0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <controls:PivotItem Background="#65006a">
            <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0">tasks</TextBlock>
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
        </controls:PivotItem>

    </controls:Pivot>
```

But it doesnt solve it.

How can I do this?

Comment: ok, sorry, I added some code

Comment: you have no content, i mean your code is correct but the header is empty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change background of title and header in pivot control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245046/change-background-of-title-and-header-in-pivot-control)

Comment: Can you try using Expression Blend? Many operations are easier there.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do it is with the following snipped:

```
<controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Background="#666666" Margin="0">
            <TextBlock FontSize="60" Margin="0" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

<controls:PivotItem Background="#65006a" Header="tasks">
</controls:PivotItem>
```

Each PivotItem has header text which is then passed to the data template contained in HeaderTemplate. You can see that I've moved TextBlock inside StackPanel and set its text via binding. What you did wrong is that header template contained *only* StackPanel and nothing inside it.

Comment: This is exactly what my answer would have been. No point repeating the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have modified the header of a pivot control. I have defined different control with different colours so you can easily identify what I have done. Modify this source as per need to change pivot header.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
          <phone:Pivot>
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Blue"
                                Margin="15,-10,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="item1">
                <Grid Background="Red"></Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem Header="item2">
                <Grid Background="Green"></Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot> 

    </Grid>
```